# Background colour showing only upon inspect in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am having a rough time with a strange problem related to background-color. Upon viewing the html file in a browser like chrome or firefox the background-color is not applying to the shop link(in the .header__shop selector). But when I inspect it and hover over the element, the background color suddenly appears in chrome and firefox.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.cdnfonts.com/css/helvetica-neue-9?styles=49034,49031,49033,49035,49032,49036,49038,49040,49042,49044,49037,49039,49041,49043,49045,49046"
      rel="stylesheet"
      crossorigin
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Assignment 4</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="header">
      <div class="header__top-ribbon">
        <a href="#" class="header__logo margin-left-small margin-right-small"
          ><img src="./images/logo.png" alt="Motorolo logo"
        /></a>
        <a href="#">Explore </a>
        <a class="header__shop" href="#">Shop</a>
        <a href="#">Customer Hub</a>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
:root {
  --header-active-background: #f2f2f2;
  --header-link-color: #00000099;
  --black: #000000;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
header a:link,
header a:visited {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--header-link-color);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding: 0 1.2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.03125rem;
}
header a:link {
  transition: all 0.5s;
}
header a:hover {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
}
/* UTILS */
.margin-left-small {
  margin-left: 2rem !important;
}
.margin-right-small {
  margin-right: 2rem !important;
}
/* header */
.header__logo img {
  height: 45%;
}
.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.header__top-ribbon {
  height: 6.4rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}
.header__shop {
  background-color: var(--header-active-background);
  font-weight: bold;
  color: var(--black) !important;
}
.header__logo {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

I have tried putting !important in

```
 background-color: var(--header-active-background);
```

in the

```
.header__shop
```

selector and it didn't work. Tried taking screenshot and snipping tool but the taken screenshot shows up the background color even if it is not there as seen by eyes!

Answer (score -1):

The background color showed up first time for me. Browsers cache pages and content (including CSS) and sometimes it helps to force refresh (Ctrl+Shift+R, or Ctrl+Click on refresh button) instead of normal refresh. Inspecting may have made the browser reload the files.